# Consecutive &nbsp; are treated as one

Tags: html

I'm converting a text-based log file with content that looks like below, to HTML by converting all space characters to `&nbsp;` using a very simple find/replace command in my PowerShell script.

```
04/20/21 12:05:14am | sogouspider-49-7-20-65.crawl.sogou.com      | https://MYWEBSITE.COM/robots.txt                  ◄ China ►          Beijing, Beijing
04/20/21 01:28:44am | dynamic-186-29-69-67.dynamic.etb.net.co     | https://MYWEBSITE.COM/_ignition/execute-soluti..  ◄ Colombia ►       Bogotá, Bogota D.C.
```

**HTML CODE:**

```html
<div style='font-family: "Source Code Pro",monospace;font-size:8px;'>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:05:14am&nbsp;|&nbsp;sogouspider-49-7-20-65.crawl.sogou.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/robots.txt&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Beijing,&nbsp;Beijing<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:08:04am&nbsp;|&nbsp;China&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;Communications&nbsp;Corporation&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;INVALID:&nbsp;[]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luoyang,&nbsp;Henan<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:08:04am&nbsp;|&nbsp;China&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;Communications&nbsp;Corporation&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luoyang,&nbsp;Henan<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:08:05am&nbsp;|&nbsp;China&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;Communications&nbsp;Corporation&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luoyang,&nbsp;Henan<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:08:05am&nbsp;|&nbsp;China&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;Communications&nbsp;Corporation&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luoyang,&nbsp;Henan<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:08:06am&nbsp;|&nbsp;China&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;Communications&nbsp;Corporation&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luoyang,&nbsp;Henan<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:08:06am&nbsp;|&nbsp;China&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;Communications&nbsp;Corporation&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luoyang,&nbsp;Henan<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:11:56am&nbsp;|&nbsp;sogouspider-49-7-20-65.crawl.sogou.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/robots.txt&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Beijing,&nbsp;Beijing<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:23:04am&nbsp;|&nbsp;54.61.236.35.bc.googleusercontent.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;United&nbsp;States&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;Los&nbsp;Angeles,&nbsp;California<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:47:35am&nbsp;|&nbsp;92.118.161.53.netsystemsresearch.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;United&nbsp;States&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
```

Whist most web browsers and Outlook email clients can display consecutive `&nbsp;` perfectly as spaces, my Android-based email reader's preview pane treats consecutive `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` as just a single `&nbsp;`

Could someone tell me the simplest way to preserve consecutive space characters in a text file to a single html text file (without any third party tools)?  My understanding is it probably can be done with `whitespace:pre` CSS property to preserve whitespace.  However, I'm not sure how to do that in the HTML file itself.
...Since when I send the email, I can only specify a single HTML file as the "body" of the email.

Comment: Since it's an email you can try inline css, https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp if you could attach the html code you have issue with, it would be much easier for people to solve this

Comment: Thanks I added my HTML code to the OP.  I just need an example of how to do the incline CSS to handle whitespaces correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the opening div tab, you can add the `white-space:pre;` right before you declare the font family.

```
<div style='white-space:pre; font-family: "Source Code Pro",monospace;font-size:8px;'>
```

you can change the value `pre` to a few different value, here is the full reference for it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

```html
<div style='white-space:pre; font-family: "Source Code Pro",monospace;font-size:8px;'>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:05:14am&nbsp;|&nbsp;sogouspider-49-7-20-65.crawl.sogou.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/robots.txt&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Beijing,&nbsp;Beijing<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:08:04am&nbsp;|&nbsp;China&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;Communications&nbsp;Corporation&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;INVALID:&nbsp;[]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luoyang,&nbsp;Henan<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:08:04am&nbsp;|&nbsp;China&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;Communications&nbsp;Corporation&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luoyang,&nbsp;Henan<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:08:05am&nbsp;|&nbsp;China&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;Communications&nbsp;Corporation&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luoyang,&nbsp;Henan<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:08:05am&nbsp;|&nbsp;China&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;Communications&nbsp;Corporation&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luoyang,&nbsp;Henan<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:08:06am&nbsp;|&nbsp;China&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;Communications&nbsp;Corporation&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luoyang,&nbsp;Henan<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:08:06am&nbsp;|&nbsp;China&nbsp;Mobile&nbsp;Communications&nbsp;Corporation&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Luoyang,&nbsp;Henan<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:11:56am&nbsp;|&nbsp;sogouspider-49-7-20-65.crawl.sogou.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/robots.txt&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;China&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Beijing,&nbsp;Beijing<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:23:04am&nbsp;|&nbsp;54.61.236.35.bc.googleusercontent.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;United&nbsp;States&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;Los&nbsp;Angeles,&nbsp;California<br>
04/20/21&nbsp;12:47:35am&nbsp;|&nbsp;92.118.161.53.netsystemsresearch.com&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;https://mywebsite.com/&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;◄&nbsp;United&nbsp;States&nbsp;►&nbsp;&nbsp;<br>
</div>
```

Comment: You're missing quote marks on that html style attribute.

Comment: Thanks.  I figured that out; especially since I originally had single quotes surrounding the style attribute.  W3schools.com displays consecutive '&nbsp;' as whitespaces whether I add `white-space:pre` as the style or not.  I won't know if this works until my script runs overnight.  Hopefully, it will do what I think it will.